# How to change the path to get screenshots to a folder named time stamp?

Tags: java, ios, appium

I have taken screen shots of appium test with following script.

```
String path;
     try {
         WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
         File source = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
         path = "/Users/admin/Desktop/newfolder" + source.getName();
              org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path));
          }
           catch(IOException e) {
                path = "Failed to capture screenshot: " + e.getMessage();
            }
```

I want to take them to a folder named with timestamp.

But now I'm getting them to desktop named like this
[image]

How to give path to a folder to save these screen shots during appium test?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to create folder with timestamp name:
*String.valueOf(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())).replace(":", "-")*

Answer (score 0):

Add a "/" after "newfolder" when you set `path =` to make it

```
path = "/Users/admin/Desktop/newfolder/" + source.getName();
```

Taking [The N…](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025512/the-n)'s answer into account, the path should be created like:

```
String timestampAsString = String.valueOf(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())).replace(":", "-");
path = "/Users/admin/Desktop/" + timestampAsString + "/" + source.getName();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that. And how to create folder with timestamp?

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question, please mark it as correct answer, thanks ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "with timestamp"? Do you want a folder named as a timestamp, like `/"Users/admin/Desktop/" + timestamp.toString() + "/" + source.getName()`? I don't know what kind of timestamp you are using, but I guess you don't want a folder named after a time in milliseconds.

Comment: yep. thats it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please mark this answer correct then, maybe also vote it up please. Thanks